# How to insert new line between Python dict value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to manipulate the dict output that showing in the html page using Flask and Jinja2 template.

I'm looking for help with

1. Adding new lines between every dict values.
2. make http text clickable for `https://example.com:8087`

The way I created my dictionary is

```
usedPort[node][z_port] =  (z_owner, docker_stack, url)
```

The expectation of the result is

```
john_doe
Zeppelin-Engineer-Individual-TAP
https://example.com:8087
```

But actually, I got

```
(john_doe, Zeppelin-Engineer-Individual-TAP, https://example.com:8087)
```

There's nothing involved print operation, I don't want to print the output in the terminal but want to show this dict value in the html page instead.

for http text, I've tried with `webbrowser module` unfortunately, It didn't work.

Comment: You need to provide the code you are using to display the `dictionary`. The dictionary is a data structure, how it's displayed is up to you.

Comment: Also, you're using a `tuple`, not a dictionary. The fact it's stored in a dictionary matters little unless you cannot control it.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `tuple`, and you do not tell how you display it. If you simply pass the `tuple`  to something that displays it (be it `print` or anything else) it will use the default representation, which is what you get.

Instead, pass what you want to actually represent:

```
'\n'.join(str(x) for x in my_tuple)  # Can use use `'\n'.join(my_tuple) if everything is a string
```

For some overkill you can define your own set (using `collection.UserTuple` or just inheriting from `tuple` which could create some problems for some uses)

```
class Tuple(tuple):
    def __repr__(self)
        return '\n'.join(str(x) for x in self)
```

The you would have to use `Tuple(...)` instead of just `(...)`, but be default you would get newlines between values anywhere.